# Prove that if a language is in co-RE it doesn't mean that it's mapping reducible to another language

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, computability

Prove/disprove: if $L\in \text{coRE}$ then $L$ is mapping-reducible to $\text{PAL}_{\text{TM}}$, where
$\text{PAL}_{\text{TM}} = \{~\langle M,w\rangle ~|~ M ~\text{is a TM and}~w~\text{is a palindrome}~\}$

It feels like there's not necessarily a mapping reduction from every language to a harder language, but I couldn't find a counter example or disprove the claim (How do I prove that a mapping doesn't exist?)

I tried playing with languages that I know that are in $\text{coRE}$, and also tried to assume towards contradiction that such a mapping exists, but it didn't really lead me anywhere.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: The usual techniques for proving that such a mapping does not exist include showing that a contradiction arises if it did.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to disprove the claim that if L is in co-RE, then L must be mapping reducible to $PAL_{TM}$.

Consider a simple language such as the empty language, denoted as $∅$.
This language contains no strings, so it is not a palindrome language, and therefore cannot be mapped reducible to $PAL_{TM}$.

However, the empty language is in co-RE because it is the complement of the language {ε}, which is RE (since it contains a single string, the empty string ε). Therefore, we have found a counterexample to the claim that if L is in co-RE, then L must be mapping reducible to $PAL_{TM}$.

Comment: How do you prove that the empty language is not reducible to $PAL_{TM}$?

Comment: To do that, you need to show that there is no function that maps every string in the empty language to a string in $PAL_{TM}$. The empty language is a language that contains no strings, so there is nothing to map. Therefore, it is impossible to construct a function that maps every string in the empty language to a string in $PAL_{TM}$, and thus the empty language is not reducible to $PAL_{TM}$. I hope it helps you!

Comment: But isn't the empy set reducible to any language?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The empty language is reducible to any language, including the palindrome language $PAL_{TM}$. However, this does not mean that the empty language is a member of the language being reduced to. In the case of $PAL_{TM}$, the empty language is not a member of the palindrome language, so it is not reducible to $PAL_{TM}$.

Comment: Think like this Let L1 be the empty language and L2 be the palindrome language.
A reduction function from L1 to L2, denoted as f, is a function that maps every string in L1 to a corresponding string in L2. Since L1 is the empty language, it contains no strings, so there is no function f that can map any strings in L1 to strings in L2. Therefore, L1 is not reducible to L2. I hope it clears your doubt.

Comment: Sorry for all my questions, but isn't the empty language decidable?Can't it simply be a turing machine that denies all inputs?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. However, this does not change the fact that the empty language is not reducible to the palindrome language $PAL_{TM}$. A language being decidable does not necessarily mean that it is reducible to another language.

Comment: But the claim relies on that $L\in coRE$, if $L=\emptyset \notin coRE$ then I can't use it as a counter example

Comment: You are getting it wrong, the empty language is in co-RE but not mapping reducible to $PAL_{TM}$, even though the claim states that all languages in co-RE must be reducible to $PAL_{TM}$.

Comment: If the empty language is decidable, then it's in $R$, and not in $coRE$, no?

Answer (score 0):

One way to prove that a reduction doesn't exist is to  prove that if a reduction *did* exist, it would lead to some result that is incompatible with the premise.  So, suppose such a reduction did exist.  What could you say about the complexity class of $L$, using that reduction?

Comment: I tried doing that, but it didn't really lead me anywhere.
If $L_1 \leq _m L_2$ it means that if $L_2\in$ coRE/RE/R then $L_1\in$ coRE/RE/R, and also if $L_1\notin$ coRE/RE/RE it means $L_2\notin$ coRE/RE/R